# What message should my MFC dialog control receive before I can modify it?

Tags: mfc

I have a custom MFC dialog **CMyDialog**, with a custom control of type **CMyControl** added using the resource editor - the dialog has a member variable for the control and has DDX set up.

The control is receiving paint messages, and has a custom on-paint handler. But I want to have the equivalent of OnInitDialog in the control, so it can safely do some initialisation when created - putting the code in the constructor leads to problems.
I tried to add handlers for WM_CREATE, WM_NCCREATE messages, and adding overrides to CWnd::Create... but none of these are firing.

What should I watching for, to know it's safe to edit stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dialog controls are attached to the MFC object when subclassed, after their creation. When `WM_CREATE` is sent, the control is not yet attached to your object and you don't get the message. You can override `PreSubclassWindow` to perform needed initialization when the control is subclassed. This will be called during MFC's handling of `WM_INITDIALOG`.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem in overriding CWnd::Create? You should be able to do it and then first call the parent method (CWnd::Create()) and then do your stuff. But in this case you will have to create the control yourself.

You can also override **PreSubclassWindow**.

Anyway, a bit more information or some code would nice to understand your problem.

Comment: By override of Create is never called.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your messagemap is set up correctly, and definitely contains WM_CREATE.
2. Check your OnCreate function signature is declared correctly.
3. Use ASSERT in your OnCreate instead of a breakpoint
   (maybe it's getting there but skipping the breakpoint)
4. Try to isolate the problem using a brand new application, then post your code if it still happens.

You might also want to follow some of [these tutorials](http://www.functionx.com/visualc/Lesson02.htm).